Checking if Two Groups of Order 100 are Isomorphic
Is $D_5 \times \mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to $D_{10} \times \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$?
I am calculating that each of these order 100 groups has the same maximal element order of 10, and the same number of elements of orders 1 (1 element), 2 (11 elements), and 5 (24 elements), hence 10. However, example 4 on page 158 of Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra text seems to suggest that I must have done something wrong.

Apparently these groups are indeed isomorphic: see Corollary 1.3 of these notes by Keith Conrad.

We have $D_{10}\cong D_5\times C_2$ and $C_{10}\cong C_5\times C_2$, because $\gcd(5,2)=1$. This yields $$D_5\times C_{10}\cong D_5\times C_2\times C_5\cong D_{10}\times C_5.$$
For the first isomorphism see this post, for example.
Let $n \geq 1$ be an odd integer. Show that $D_{2n}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times D_n$.

This answer would be perfect if it explained or included a link explaining the first isomorphism.

I have included a link. Also, Greg gave a link in his comment.
